# Batch File - Hosts file editor - prevent duplicate entries - delete previously added entries

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Okay here is what I got so far.
This is meant to add websites to block in the hosts file, as well as allow the user to delete the entries when they want to. When trying to add a website to block sometimes it creates a new line then puts the entry on the line before it. This is not what I want. I want it to create a new line then add the entry on that line. For some reason it works sometimes and other times it don't work at all. I get an error message that says Find parameter is incorrect. I am using the Find command to see if the entries is already in the hosts file. If it is I want it to avoid adding it. If it is not then I want to add it. When I try to delete a entry the batch just crashes, so I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to find the entry and replace it with nothing. What I really want to do is delete the entire line so that I don't end up with a lot of blank lines.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
@echo off
TITLE Modifying your HOSTS file
COLOR F0

:LOOP
cls
SET "CHOICE="
ECHO Choose 1 to block a website 
ECHO Choose 2 remove a blocked website 
ECHO Choose 3 to exit
SET /P CHOICE= selection %CHOICE%
GOTO %CHOICE%

:1
cls
SET /P WEBSITE=Enter the name of the website to add:
SET HOME=     127.0.0.1 
SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
SET BLOCKEDSITE=%HOME% %WEBSITE%

FIND /C /I %BLOCKEDSITE% %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 ECHO %NEWLINE%^%BLOCKEDSITE%>>%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
ECHO Website blocked
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul
GOTO LOOP

:2
cls
SET /P WEBSITE=Enter the name of the website to remove:

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENTIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "HOME=     127.0.0.1 "
SET "BLOCKEDSITE=%HOME% %WEBSITE%"
SET "REPLACE="
SET "HOSTSFILE=%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%i IN ('TYPE "%HOSTSFILE%" ^& BREAK ^> "%HOSTSFILE%" ') 
DO 
(
    SET "LINE=%%i"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    >>"%HOSTSFILE%" echo(!LINE:%BLOCKEDSITE%=%REPLACE%!
    ENDLOCAL
)

ECHO Website unblocked

GOTO LOOP

:3
EXIT
```

Comment: So what line generates the error message? Please read [Debugging batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php) and [edit] your question.

Comment: The procedure can be performed more simply and directly using the 'find/replace' function in almost all text editors, more especially those accepting 'regular expression' terms. I see no reason for to make the process more difficult or long winded by using a batch file, allowing uncontrolled end user entry, and writing to temporary files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the term `website` is misleading when referring to the entries of the `hosts` file. The entries of `hosts` file are used for custom mappings of DNS host names to IP addresses, and any host name that is present in the file does not necessarily hosts a website. Using the term `website` may lead to the false impression that something like `http://www.example.com` can be added to hosts file which is not true.

**Skipping a host if it is already present in the hosts file:**
The problem with your usage of `find` is that `%BLOCKEDSITE%` has embedded spaces so you should enclose it quotes and use:

```
FIND /C /I "%BLOCKEDSITE%" %WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

But it has another problem: Because of its dependency on the exact spacing between the IP address and host name which is mandated by `%BLOCKEDSITE%` It only works for the entries that are added by your batch file. Additionally the user may have commented out (disabled) an entry by placing `#` in the begging of the line that contains the entry, and your batch code will skip adding the host even if the entry is disabled.

This can be resolved by using `findstr` with its regex syntax. for example:

```
findstr /IRC:"^ *127\.0\.0\.1 *example\.com *$" "%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

**Removing an entry from the hosts file:**
In the `FOR` loop you just have to skip writing the lines that contains the specified entry:

```
if "!Line!"=="!LINE:%BLOCKEDSITE%=!" echo(!Line!>>"%HOSTSFILE%"
```

But again it is not accurate and is suffering from the same problems that are mentioned earlier for skipping adding the entry. Again By using `findstr` you can easily remove the lines that contain the unwanted entry:

```
findstr /VIRC:"^ *127\.0\.0\.1 *example\.com *$" "%HOSTSFILE%" > "%HOSTSFILE%.tmp"
del "%HOSTSFILE%"
ren "%HOSTSFILE%.tmp" "hosts"
```

With above mentioned points the script can be rewritten like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
title Modifying your HOSTS file
color F0

set "HOSTSFILE=%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
set "HOME=127.0.0.1"
set "PROMPT_TEXT=Enter the host name to"
set "ACTION_TEXT[1]=add"
set "ACTION_TEXT[2]=remove"
set "FindEmptyLine=^ *$"
set "NewLineAppended="
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:LOOP
echo,
echo 1. Block a host
echo 2. Remove a blocked host
echo 3. Exit
choice /C "123" /N /M "Choose an item [1, 2, 3]: "
set "Item=%errorlevel%"

goto choice%Item%

:choice0 // User Pressed CTRL-C
:choice3
exit /b

:choice1
call :Common
set "HostEntry=!HOME! !HOST!"
findstr /IRC:"!FindEntry!" "!HOSTSFILE!"> nul && (
    echo The host !HOST! is already blocked, No action taken.
) || (
    if not defined NewLineAppended (
        REM This will append a new line ONLY if the file does not end by LF character
        type "!HOSTSFILE!" | findstr $ > "!HOSTSFILE!.tmp" && (
            del "!HOSTSFILE!"
            ren "!HOSTSFILE!.tmp" "hosts"
            set "NewLineAppended=1"
        )
    )
    echo !HostEntry!>>"!HOSTSFILE!"
    echo The host !HOST! blocked
)
goto LOOP

:choice2
call :Common
findstr /VIR /C:"!FindEntry!" /C:"!FindEmptyLine!" "!HOSTSFILE!">"!HOSTSFILE!.tmp" && (
    del "!HOSTSFILE!"
    ren "!HOSTSFILE!.tmp" "hosts"
    echo The host !HOST! unblocked
)
goto LOOP

:Common
set "HOST="
set /P "HOST=!PROMPT_TEXT! !ACTION_TEXT[%Item%]! (e.g. example.com): "
if not defined HOST (
    (goto)2>nul
    goto LOOP
)
set "FindEntry=^^ *!HOME! *!HOST! *$"
set "FindEntry=!FindEntry:.=\.!"
exit /b
```